# wordpress + woocommerce display product with additional information

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I had created 1 plugin name "places" now i want to allow the customer to select the product with the places(as a dropdown) which i had enter though my custom plugin. How do i achieve it ?

=> Plugin contain on insert,update,delete and searching with the table called "wp_places",

=> I had install woocommarce and now i want to display the "place as dropdown" for selection while doing purchase.

Comment: do you want the drop-down to be displayed  in Single product page only?  do you want the selected option to be saved to db did you do that in your plugin?

Comment: @kashalo I want to create my custom short code which contain form and in that form i want to use dropdown (all product)  and other dropdown(which contain data from the custom plugin )